# Two variables with different values and IF statement isn't working on them if in the same loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, pycharm

Okay, lets say I have three variables with different values, taking input from the user, and if input equals say variable a then print variable b in a string. I can't see a code to do this but if I use or for the two variables in the is statement it work. See code below

Comment: The code is missing.

Comment: Where is the code?
Also, Problem is not clear from the statement, I would have coded If there was some code for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to give a basic structure as there is no code given, you can modify according to your problem.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
val = int(input('Enter a number'))
if val == a:
    print(b)
elif val == b:
    print(c)
else:
    print(b)
```

Comment: Okay, I forgot to share the code. my bad, I'm sure this should work.